# How to send Health Data to Tangle via MAM?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, seed, masked-authenticated-messaging

I am trying to make a project to send Health data from my phone to Tangle via MAM. For this purpose, I have made a sample file that publishes sample health data to Tangle. When I am running the code, it is throwing an exception of 'failed to attach message'.

Can someone guide what could possibly be the reason?

```
const Mam = require('./lib/mam.client.js');
const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js');
const moment = require('moment');
const iota = new IOTA({ provider: 'https://nodes.devnet.iota.org'});
const { asciiToTrytes, trytesToAscii } = require('@iota/converter')
const mode = 'restricted'
const secretKey = 'VERYSECRETKEY'
const provider = 'https://nodes.devnet.iota.org'

const mamExplorerLink = `https://mam-explorer.firebaseapp.com/?provider=${encodeURIComponent(provider)}&mode=${mode}&key=${secretKey.padEnd(81, '9')}&root=`

let numberofSteps;
let kilometersWalked;

// Initialise MAM State
let mamState = Mam.init(provider)

// Set channel mode
mamState = Mam.changeMode(mamState, mode, secretKey)

// Publish data to the tangle
const publish = async packet => {
        // Create MAM Payload - STRING OF TRYTES
        const trytes = asciiToTrytes(JSON.stringify(packet))
        const message = Mam.create(mamState, trytes)
         // Save new mamState
        mamState = message.state
         // Attach the payload
        await Mam.attach(message.payload, message.address)    
        console.log('Published', packet, '\n');
        console.log (message.root);
        return message.root
    }

const publishAll = async () => {
    const root = await publish({
        numberofSteps: Math.floor((Math.random()*89)+10),
        kilometersWalked: (numberofSteps/1312.335),
        message: 'Message from Alice',
        timestamp: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
      })

      await publish({
        numberofSteps: Math.floor((Math.random()*89)+10),
        kilometersWalked: Math.floor(990/9),
        message: 'Message from Alice',
        timestamp: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
      })

      await publish({
        numberofSteps: Math.floor((Math.random()*89)+10),
        kilometersWalked: Math.floor(990/9),
        message: 'Message from Alice',
        timestamp: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
      })

      return root
}

publishAll()
```

Also, is there any possible way to automatically send Health data from iphone or android? I don't want the user to send the data, instead the process should be automated. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested your code and it worked for me. This is an example of the response:

```
NVYRBTEAJAYAJMWIAHRMZNT9PQMIUWFTLQOB9RVAIWDLDOSZHPJCWEGNF9JTZLCTULRFCWFEAFAPUIMFM
Published
Object {numberofSteps: 14, kilometersWalked: 110, message: "Message from Alice", timestamp: "12/4/2019, 8:28:51 AM"}
```

To do this automatically, you could set up events in the code that collects health data. This way, your MAM code can be triggered whenever new health data events are emitted.

Comment: I'm getting this exception:  failed to attach message: 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransfer' of undefined
    at _callee5$ (C:\Users\Sidra\Desktop\project\lib\mam.client.js:23390:46)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\Sidra\Desktop\project\lib\mam.client.js:28056:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke]

Comment: After this exception, the data is published: <br/> 
Published {
  numberofSteps: 70,
  kilometersWalked: 110,
  message: 'Message from Alice',
  timestamp: '12/4/2019, 10:20:23 AM'
}